# Kotlin crash on arrayadapter in fragment: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I have to make a simple application for school but for some reason my app keeps crashing on the following error:

```
System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
```

After a bit of debugging i found out that it crashes on the ArrayAdapter creation. I tried a lot of things but for some reason it keeps on crashing with the same error.

I already tried a lot of things including:
- running it in the MainActivity (which yielded the best results)
- running it directly in the onCreate()
- running it in the onViewCreated()
- and a few other places...

I wanted to make a simple friends app where people can enter their data in my phone, nothing to amazing. I need to retrieve the data from a url, i used myjson.org to create a simple json (that's the assignment). All the data i get is receive from the url is correct and the list is also complete. I just don't know how to attach it to the list...

```
package com.vb.vriendenboekje8.ui.home

import android.app.Activity
import android.content.Context
import android.os.AsyncTask
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter
import android.widget.ListView
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity
import com.vb.vriendenboekje8.MainActivity
import com.vb.vriendenboekje8.R
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.*
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.fragment_home.view.*
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.net.URL

class HomeFragment : Fragment()
{
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View?
    {
        val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)

        var lstFriends : ListView = view.findViewById(R.id.lstFriends)

        LoadJsonTask(lstFriends).execute("<url to json here>")

        return view
    }

    class LoadJsonTask(lstFriends : ListView) : AsyncTask<String, Void, String>()
    {
        var lstFriends : ListView

        init
        {
            this.lstFriends = lstFriends
        }

        //load http request and get Json data
        override fun doInBackground(vararg params: String?) : String
        {
            var json : String

            val stringURL = params[0]
            json = URL(stringURL).readText()

            return json
        }

        override fun onPostExecute(result: String?)
        {
            super.onPostExecute(result)

            val friendsJson = JSONArray(result)
            var friendsList : MutableList<String> = mutableListOf()

            //clear the friends list
            friendsList.clear()

            //add names to list
            for (i in 0..(friendsJson.length()-1))
            {
                val friend : JSONObject = friendsJson[i] as JSONObject
                friendsList.add(friend.get("Naam") as String)
            }

            val adapter = ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, friendsList) //where the app crashes
            this.lstFriends.setAdapter(adapter)
        }
    }
}
```

my fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstFriends"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

full error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.vb.vriendenboekje8, PID: 31342
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: System services not available to Activities before onCreate()
        at android.app.Activity.getSystemService(Activity.java:6649)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.from(LayoutInflater.java:284)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:216)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:210)
        at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.<init>(ArrayAdapter.java:196)
        at com.vb.vriendenboekje8.ui.home.HomeFragment$LoadJsonTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.kt:76)
        at com.vb.vriendenboekje8.ui.home.HomeFragment$LoadJsonTask.onPostExecute(HomeFragment.kt:39)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:755)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$900(AsyncTask.java:192)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:772)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7682)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
```

If anyone has any ideas or sees something i do wrong please let me know.

PS im new to kotlin and android development

Comment: `ArrayAdapter<String>(FragmentActivity()...` is something strange (and not only this). Maybe `ArrayAdapter<String>(context!!...` ?

Comment: @DrawnRaccoon changing it with view.context worked! thanks!